# Change image src with jquery for 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with how to change an image src with another one for 5 seconds before reverting back to the default one with jquery.

below is a code I am trying to use.

```
$('#indicator').attr("src", 'notification.png');
```

I need to change it for 5 seconds only.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {$('#indicator').attr("src", 'previous_image.png');}, 5000)`

Comment: Zero-Effort. Simple search on google or SO should produce several solutions. So far this question is primarily opinion based as you have nothing done yourself. [**How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users before posting a Question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/448144)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just two scripts

```
$('#indicator').attr("src", 'notification-new.png');
```

and

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#indicator').attr("src", 'notification.png'); }, 5000);
```

The first one changes the attribute to a new src and the second one changes it back to the original state after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldSrc = $('#indicator').attr("src"); //save old image source
$('#indicator').attr("src", 'notification.png'); //set new image source
setTimeout(function(){ $('#indicator').attr("src", oldSrc); }, 5000); // after 5 seconds, reset old image source
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

```
var changeSrc = function(obj){
    var elem = jQuery(obj.selector), img = elem.attr('src'); elem.attr('src', obj.tmpSrc);
    setTimeout(function(){elem.attr('src', img);}, 1000*obj.revertAfter);
};

changeSrc({
    selector: 'your-img-selector-here',
    tmpSrc: 'your-tmp-img-src-here',
    revertAfter: 5
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.